# Sorting of numbers within brackets in angular datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using [Angular datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) to populate my table based on a webservice response. My webservice returns me a json like below

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name" : "abc",
  "count": "(20)"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name" : "abc2",
   "count": "20"
 },
{
  "id": 3,
  "name" : "abc3",
  "count": "(30)"
 }
]
```

I am able to bind the JSON array to my $scope variable in the table below

```
<table  datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
     <thead>
             <tr> 
                 <th>id</th>
                 <th>name</th>
                 <th>count</th>
             </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody ng-repeat= "item in items">
         <td> {{item.id}} </td>
         <td> {{item.name}} </td>
         <td> {{item.count}} </td>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

The **id** and **name** columns are sorted properly in ascending and descending order but the **count** column is not sorted based on the numbers. Instead it takes the "(" into account while sorting and the sorting. I want the sort result for the count column to be

In ascending

20

(20)

(30)

Right now i get in ascending order

(20)

(30)

20

Can anyone suggest what is the logic i need to apply?

Comment: How are you sorting them ?

Comment: There is no difference `(20) == 20` Or is it a string and you forgot to add the quotes in your markup?

Comment: What's with the `(number)` format? `"count": (20)` is invalid json so it's hard to tell what you are working with exactly or even why that format exists

Comment: Hi I have edited the question now. It was a typo error. I am not adding any sorting logic as of now. I am just binding the data I receive to my table. The default sort gives me the order (20), (30), 20 which I dont want. Instead I need it to be 20, (20) and (30) in ascending

Comment: @charlietfl : is the question clear now?

Comment: Not entirely, what is the `(number)` format supposed to represent? you will either need to convert to number or write a custom sorter function per datatables docs

Comment: (number) format is used to represent the count of items. As per the default datatable sorting logic..it sorts numbers properly in ascending and descending. however in mycase I need the sorting to happen treating the count as a number so that I get the desired result. BTW, the count will be displayed as (20) only in the table. I just need a solution to sort the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a column render function. When ever dataTables need values for the `count` column, and want to use the value to `sort` the column, then pass back a typed number containing the number part of the column data :

```js
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [
   DTColumnDefBuilder
     .newColumnDef(2)
     .withOption('type', 'number')
     .renderWith(function(data, type, full) {
        if (type == 'sort') { 
           var value = data.match(/\d+/);
           if (value == null) {
              return 0
           } else {
              value = parseFloat(value[0]);
           } 
           return value.toString().length != data.length ? value+0.0001 : value;
        } 
        return data              
    })
];
```

Here I add `0.0001` to values that contain illegal characters, like `(` - by that we can be sure values is displayed in the correct order, i.e all `20` is grouped *together* before (or after) all `(20)`.

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/Zyp0yphHfxnElEjMMOh2?p=preview**

---

NB: I would iterate over the `<tr>`'s, not `<tbody>` :

```html
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
        <td> {{item.id}} </td>
        <td> {{item.name}} </td>
        <td> {{item.count}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```