# Angular 6 DataTables - Table Items Appear/Disappear Upon Sort or Search

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sorting, angular-datatables

I am using Angular-DataTables 6.0 (found here https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) and I have been running into a reoccurring problem. When a table item is added or deleted, the record either vanishes or reappears upon sorting or searching. Is this possibly because the adding/deleting is occurring from outside the dataTable?

I've tried adding the ' datatable="ng" ' fix many others suggested but that didn't change anything. I also attempted to add a re-render function, but in that case I ran into 'object unsubscribed' errors that I couldn't resolve. For reference, some similar problems can be found here: Similar examples include: ([angular : lost data after sort datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921174/angular-lost-data-after-sort-datatable))
([Sorting of numbers within brackets in angular datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475966/sorting-of-numbers-within-brackets-in-angular-datatables))
(https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/852)

Here is my code:

```
HTML:
  <table datatable="ng" [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table table-hover" id="t1">
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <button id="b5">Asset ID</button>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button id="b5">Employee ID</button>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <button id="b5">Asset Type</button>
                                </th>
                                <th>View</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let a of assets; let i = index"> 
          <td>{{ a.assetID }}</td>
          <td>{{ a.currentUser }}</td>
          <td>{{ a.assetType }}</td>
          <td><button id="button1" (click)="viewAsset(a)"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button></td>
          <td><button id="b2" class="btn" (click)="scrapAsset(a)" (mouseenter)="buttonHover(i)" (mouseleave)="buttonHoverLeave(i)"><i class="{{buttonIconArray[i].text}}"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
-elsewhere in the code-
         <button class="btn" id="b1" (click)="addAsset()">Add New Asset</button>&nbsp;
```

TS

```
   dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
   dtTrigger = new Subject();

 addAsset()
 {
this.confirmChanges = false;
//Create a new asset:
let a: Asset = {
  assetID: this.assetID,
  currentUser: this.currentUser,
  assetType: this.dropdownMessage,

}
//send a notification to the user that owns the new asset
  let notify: Notice = {
  emplyID: a.currentUser,
  notificationSource: "Asset",
  details: "A new " + this.dropdownMessage + " was added to your assets.",
  timeStamp: new Date()
}

//Add the asset to the server
this.AssetsService.addAsset(a)
      .subscribe(asset => { this.assets.unshift(asset);
                            //All of the inputs need to be emptied
                            this.clearFields(); 
                          })
}

scrapAsset(a: Asset)
{
console.log("The ID is " , a.assetID)
//this.AssetsService.deleteAsset(this.currentAsset).subscribe()
this.confirmChanges = false;



//This deletes the asset from the back-end.
this.AssetsService.deleteAsset(a).subscribe(() => { 
  console.log('test')
  this.assets = this.assets.filter(t => t !== a);
  this.NotificationsService.addNotice(notify).subscribe();
  this.clearFields(); });
  }

dtActivate()
 {
this.dtOptions = {
pagingType: 'full_numbers',
pageLength: 7,
order: (this.assets.assetType),
orderClasses: false,
};
this.AssetsService.getAssetsIT().subscribe((assetsImported) => {
this.assets = assetsImported;
this.parseData();
  // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
  this.dtTrigger.next();
});
}
```

This is only a partial section of the code, so if you need to see more, just ask. Thank you for any help you might provide!

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I have not. The solution below didn't help my original problem.

Comment: i fixed it, let me know if you want to find the solution

Comment: Absolutely, go ahead and post the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem for a long time. After a lot of stack overflow and documentation, I found a solution that fixed my problem. Maybe it helps you too.

## Allow datatable to be destroyed

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dtOptions = {
    destroy: true,
    ...
  };
  ...
}
```

## The method that received new items (called after edit, insert, add...).

```
onReceived(items){
    let isFirst = this.items.length === 0;
    this.items = <itemsModel[]>items;

    if (isFirst)
      this.dtTrigger.next();
    else
      this.rerender();
}
```

## The rerender as in documentation

```
rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        dtInstance.destroy();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
}
```

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

I hope that this might help you.

Comment: Alright, I just tested this code out, and it seemed to partially work. The DataTable did update in real time, however, I got an error that appears as a popup: "DataTables warning: table id=t1 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3".

Comment: sorry.. there's one more thing, I will try to update the answer, you have to allow the destroy.

Comment: I had one bug with this code once because my list can change from empty to not empty at one particular case (so sometimes rerender was not called). So the condition for the first time has to be evaluated in your case.

Comment: dear @Danchat could you test the modification I did?

Comment: I'll try to get to it tomorrow if I can. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I no longer get the error, but the DataTable is not updating in real time anymore. Filtering/sorting the table eliminates the new entry... I believe my post from 2 days ago was incorrect because the table had already been updating in real time, it's just been months since I've worked on this.

Comment: are you calling rerender everytime your datatable is changed (adding, removing, ...) and did you called dtTrigger.next(); the first time your databales was filled ?

Comment: The answer to your first question is no and the second is yes. After placing rerender(), the dataTable did not get rid of the new record. Deleting worked too. I believe I had falsely assumed that rerender() was getting called automatically from something within the DataTable code... but thanks for the help! This problem has been finally solved!

Comment: I am glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

this will work, but i am still looking for better solutions 
`setTimeout(function () {$(function () {$('#ng').DataTable();});}, 10);`

Comment: Where in the code are you putting this? I tried placing this after adding or removing an entry in the datatable but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Danchat set it inside `ngOnInit() { setTimeout(function () {$(function () {$('#ng').DataTable();});}, 50); }`, inside your component, so when page is load it will render your datatable

Comment: The Datatable itself is rendering fine, but my problem is that the table cannot be updated (add or delete records) without refreshing the webpage. Putting this code in ngOnInit didn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the ng, Following code fixed my problem

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h4>Milk Types</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">  

                    <a href="" class="btn btn-success" href=''  [routerLink]="['/milk/create-milk']">
                        <i class="ti-zip pdd-right-5"></i>
                        <span>Add New Milk</span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="table-overflow">
                        <table class="table table-lg table-hover" datatable [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>                                    
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Price</th>
                                    <th></th>   
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let drink of data">                                    
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="mrg-top-15">
                                            <b class="text-dark font-size-16">{{ drink.id }}</b>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="mrg-top-15">
                                            <span class="text-info pdd-left-20"><b>{{ drink.name }}</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td>
                                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <div class="toggle-checkbox toggle-success checkbox-inline">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name="isEnabled" id="toggle4" [checked]="drink.isEnabled">
                                                    <label for="toggle4"></label>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="mrg-top-15">
                                            <span class="text-info"><b>KD {{ drink.price }}</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>  
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="mrg-top-10 text-center">
                                            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">
                                                <i class="ti-comment pdd-right-5"></i>
                                                <span>Edit</span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>    



import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy , ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { pipe, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MilksItem, MilksDataSource } from './milks-datasource';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component ({
    templateUrl: 'milk.html'
})

export class MilkComponent implements OnInit {

    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    subscription: Subscription;
    data: MilksItem[] = [];
    dtTrigger: Subject<MilksItem> = new Subject();

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) 
    {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.dtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers'
        };

        this.subscription = this.db.list<MilksItem>('milkTypes').valueChanges().subscribe(d=>{
          console.log('data streaming');
          this.data = d;
          this.dtTrigger.next();
        });    
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did my best to replicate your code and I wasn't able to get it to work. Since I'm using services and MongoDB as the back-end and I tried using 'subscription' like you did, perhaps there was some sort of incompatibility there. Is there any way you could put this code up on a place like Plunker and then I could see how the code works running live?

Answer (score 0):

## Another Working Solution

*Just move your data-table inside a separate component*

*AND*

*Provide your new options/data as an `Input()`*

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.scss']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(DataTableDirective, { static: false }) dt!: DataTableDirective;

  @Input() dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  private _initComponent() {
    this.dtTrigger.next(this.dtOptions);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._initComponent();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

```html
<table #dtA datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
    class="custom-dt-1 table table-sm table-striped card-table w-full row-border hover">
</table>
```